# How to include timestamp in logs of VerneMQ

Tags: logging, timestamp, mqtt-vernemq

Unhappily, the logs of the vernemq broker do not include a timestamp. Current workaround seems to be to include the timestamp in the message sent to some vernemq topic and then strip it off at the consumer side. This requires changing 2 programs. Is there some other way to make vernemq write the current time to every line in the log? Through configuration maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Verne log lines contain timestamps. Why would you send a message with a timestamp?
Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: "Verne log lines contain timestamps. ". No, they don't. That is the point of the question I posted here.